# how to set inter_op_parallelism_threads and intra_op_parallelism_threads for seesion configuration in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

If you use an MKL build of TF, the threading model becomes OpenMP rather than Pthreads. Controlling the number of threads and their affinity is critical to getting good CPU performance. One can do something like below in some cases:

```
 config = tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=FLAGS.inter_op,intra_op_parallelism_threads=FLAGS.intra_op)
 sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

But this mechanism does not seem to work with the rnn tutorial app

> ptb /tensorflow/tensorflow/models/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py

which I think uses

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=FLAGS.save_path)
```

to define the session
adding

```
inter_op_parallelism_threads=FLAGS.inter_op,intra_op_parallelism_threads=FLAGS.intra_op
```

to that invocation fails.
So how in general can one set these flags?

Comment: What is FLAGS?!

Answer (score 0):

the solution for ptb_word_lm.py seems to be to add

config = tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=FLAGS.inter_op,intra_op_parallelism_threads=FLAGS.intra_op)

sess = tf.Session(config=config)

before the call to the ptb_reader thereby setting the session env.
(along with some OMP* env variables)